# Verilog - creating a timer to count a second

Tags: verilog, hdl

I'm using a FPGA (BEMICROMAX10) to create a digital clock using seven segment displays on a breadboard, and I'm having issues getting the seconds to count exactly 1 second. The clock system input I'm using is 50 MHz. I'm going to post just the relevant code to the seconds. The equation I used to determine N was (1/50000000) * 2^N = 1 which gave me 25.58, so when I use 26, it's just a tad slow, and when I make it 25, it's a little too fast. Any ideas how to correct this?

Thank you

```
module digital_clock(clk, segsec);
input clk;
output [13:0] segsec;

parameter N = 25;
reg [N-1:0] slow_clk = 0;
reg [7:0] countsec = 0;

always @ (posedge clk)
    slow_clk <= slow_clk + 1'b1;

always @ (posedge slow_clk[N-1])
    if (countsec == 8'b00111011) countsec <= 8'b0;
    else  countsec <= countsec + 8'b1;

assign segsec = (countsec == 8'h0 ) ? 16'b01111110111111:
    (countsec == 8'h1) ? 16'b01111110000110: //1        0000110     0111111
    (countsec == 8'h2) ? 16'b01111111011011: //2        1011011
    (countsec == 8'h3) ? 16'b01111111001111: //3        1001111
    (countsec == 8'h4) ? 16'b01111111100110: //4        1100110
    (countsec == 8'h5) ? 16'b01111111101101: //5        1101101
    (countsec == 8'h6) ? 16'b01111111111101: //6        1111101
    (countsec == 8'h7) ? 16'b01111110000111: //7        0000111
    (countsec == 8'h8) ? 16'b01111111111111: //8        1111111
    (countsec == 8'h9) ? 16'b01111111101111: //9        1101111
    (countsec == 8'ha) ? 16'b00001100111111: //10
    (countsec == 8'hb) ? 16'b00001100000110://11
    (countsec == 8'hc) ? 16'b00001101011011://12
    (countsec == 8'hd) ? 16'b00001101001111://13
    (countsec == 8'he) ? 16'b00001101100110: //14
    (countsec == 8'hf) ? 16'b00001101101101: //15
    (countsec == 8'h10) ? 16'b00001101111101://16
    (countsec == 8'h11) ? 16'b00001100000111://17
    (countsec == 8'h12) ? 16'b00001101111111://18
    (countsec == 8'h13) ? 16'b00001101101111://19
    (countsec == 8'h14) ? 16'b10110110111111://20
    (countsec == 8'h15) ? 16'b10110110000110://21
    (countsec == 8'h16) ? 16'b10110111011011://22
    (countsec == 8'h17) ? 16'b10110111001111://23
    (countsec == 8'h18) ? 16'b10110111100110://24
    (countsec == 8'h19) ? 16'b10110111101101://25
    (countsec == 8'h1a) ? 16'b10110111111101://26
    (countsec == 8'h1b) ? 16'b10110110000111://27
    (countsec == 8'h1c) ? 16'b10110111111111://28
    (countsec == 8'h1d) ? 16'b10110111101111://29
    (countsec == 8'h1e) ? 16'b10011110111111://30
    (countsec == 8'h1f) ? 16'b10011110000110://31
    (countsec == 8'h20) ? 16'b10011111011011://32
    (countsec == 8'h21) ? 16'b10011111001111://33
    (countsec == 8'h22) ? 16'b10011111100110://34
    (countsec == 8'h23) ? 16'b10011111101101://35
    (countsec == 8'h24) ? 16'b10011111111101://36
    (countsec == 8'h25) ? 16'b10011110000111://37
    (countsec == 8'h26) ? 16'b10011111111111://38
    (countsec == 8'h27) ? 16'b10011111101111://39
    (countsec == 8'h28) ? 16'b11001100111111://40
    (countsec == 8'h29) ? 16'b11001100000110://41
    (countsec == 8'h2a) ? 16'b11001101011011://42
    (countsec == 8'h2b) ? 16'b11001101001111://43
    (countsec == 8'h2c) ? 16'b11001101100110://44
    (countsec == 8'h2d) ? 16'b11001101101101://45
    (countsec == 8'h2e) ? 16'b11001101111101://46
    (countsec == 8'h2f) ? 16'b11001100000111://47
    (countsec == 8'h30) ? 16'b11001101111111://48
    (countsec == 8'h31) ? 16'b11001101101111://49
    (countsec == 8'h32) ? 16'b11011010111111://50
    (countsec == 8'h33) ? 16'b11011010000110://51
    (countsec == 8'h34) ? 16'b11011011011011://52
    (countsec == 8'h35) ? 16'b11011011001111://53
    (countsec == 8'h36) ? 16'b11011011100110://54
    (countsec == 8'h37) ? 16'b11011011101101://55
    (countsec == 8'h38) ? 16'b11011011111101://56
    (countsec == 8'h39) ? 16'b11011010000111://57
    (countsec == 8'h3a) ? 16'b11011011111111://58
    (countsec == 8'h3b) ? 16'b11011011101111://59
    16'b01111110111111;
endmodule
```

Comment: For what it's worth, this question might be more appropriate on the [Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: An [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would have been more helpful. I had to write a testbench for this - you could have done that for me. Also, the huge assign statement at the bottom is not relevant to your problem.

Comment: Just out of interest: why are you using the old-fashioned, pre-2001 I/O style? Who has taught you to do this? I ask, because I teach Verilog myself, and would never teach that. Yet the overwhelming majority of questions from people learning Verilog here use the old-fashioned style. I have used the more modern, "ANSI" style on [EDA Playground](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/4eeB).

Comment: FYI, long nested conditional operators (`? :`) will typically synthesize with horribly long and unbalanced propagation delay. The synthesizers I've worked treat each conditional operator as explicit 2:1 mux. You should use a case statement in an `always @*` block

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, there are three ways to approach this:

1. Use a separate clock source with a more appropriate frequency (e.g, 1.048576 MHz = 2<sup>20</sup> Hz). The board you're using doesn't appear to have any sockets for a clock crystal, but you could potentially attach one to one of the GPIO pins.
2. Use one of the PLLs in the FPGA to convert your 50 MHz clock to an appropriate frequency. Refer to the [MAX 10 Clocking and PLL User Guide](https://www.altera.com/en_US/pdfs/literature/hb/max-10/ug_m10_clkpll.pdf) for details.
3. Use a phase accumulator to generate a 1 PPS (pulse per second) signal:

   ```
   reg [25:0] accum = 0;
   wire pps = (accum == 0);

   always @(posedge clk) begin
       accum <= (pps ? 50_000_000 : accum) - 1;

       if (pps) begin
           … things to do once per second …
       end
   end
   ```

   This architecture uses a single clock signal for all logic, rather than generating a separate, slower clock from combinational logic. (For various reasons, you're best off using as few different clocks as possible.)

Comment: Hey Dusk, thank you for the help. I tried the code you provided for your third option and it worked, but for testing the hours, I need to speed up the seconds and I'm not sure how you would do that with this type of setup. In my original code, I would just drop the N value down from 26 to 19 and it would zoom through the secs and mins in almost a minute to reach the next hour, but I'm not sure with yours.

Comment: Change the number from 50 million (`50_000_000`; the underscores are ignored) to a smaller one.

Comment: I have downvoted your answer, because I don't think adjusting the clock frequency is a practical thing to do. The choice of clock frequency is usually an architectural decision based many factors. Making a counter wrap-around at 49,999,999 is surely far more practical? By all means correct me if I'm wrong and I will reverse it.

Comment: @MatthewTaylor In this case, the choice of clock frequency was made by the manufacturer of the development board. I'm enumerating all the available options for the sake of completeness, and having a counter that wraps at 50e6-1 is exactly what I'm describing in the third option.

Comment: If you edit it, I'll change my vote. It won't let me change it otherwise.

Comment: I'm sorry. What is to me a rather unconventional coding style, calling it a "phase accumulator" and the earlier references to clock frequencies hid the design intent from me. I should have read it more carefully.

Comment: @MatthewTaylor Edited.

Answer (score 0):

Your equation has enabled the calculation of the number of bits you need for your counter; in this case you need a 26-bit counter. But a counter can wrap around at any value you like; it doesn't need to wrap around at all ones. You know that already, because your other counter already has logic to make it wrap around at 8'b00111011 (59). So, change this:

```
always @ (posedge clk)
    slow_clk <= slow_clk + 1'b1;
```

to this:

```
always @ (posedge clk)
    if (slow_clk == 26'd49999999) slow_clk <= 8'b0;
    else  slow_clk <= slow_clk + 8'b1;
```

I also notice that your counter is only 25 bits. This:

```
parameter N = 25;
```

should be this:

```
parameter N = 26;
```

**However**, as someone mentioned under your previous question, you have a *derived clock*. You don't need a derived clock here and you should always avoid using derived clocks if you can. Derived clocks are not *synchronous design*  and so can cause big problems unless you know what you're doing. So, don't clock your second `always` block with `slow_clk[N-1]`, clock it with `clk` and use `slow_clk[N-1]` as an enable signal. Don't do this:

```
always @ (posedge slow_clk[N-1])
    if (countsec == 8'b00111011) countsec <= 8'b0;
    else  countsec <= countsec + 8'b1;
```

do this:

```
assign enable = (slow_clk == 26'd49999999);

always @ (posedge clk)
  if (enable == 1'b1)
    if (countsec == 8'b00111011) countsec <= 8'b0;
    else  countsec <= countsec + 8'b1;
```

Here is a version (**speeded up by a factor of 1000000**) on EDA Playground:

http://www.edaplayground.com/x/4eeB

Answer (score 0):

Easy, for my project i just count pos clocks 12Mhz and get exactly one sec look at the exapmle below

```
always_ff@(posedge clock or negedge reset) 
    begin       
        if (~reset | ~led1R)
            begin
                Counttimer <= 0;
            end

        else if (Counttimer < 'hB71B00) 
            begin
                Counttimer <= Counttimer + 1;
            end

        else if ( Counttimer >= 'hB71B00) //3008
            begin

                Counttimer <= 0;
            end
    end
```